# EF6 Fluent API to add varchar foreign keys to values with trailing spaces

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have an existing legacy SQL Server database on which I need to do some mappings with EF.

I have problems with a foreign key which is linked to a `varchar(2)` primary key.

The problem is at records where the primary key has trailing space and the other table has the same value without the trailing space, the link object will be null (on SQL Server it joins them just fine, it returns the correct data with SQL trace, somehow it is lost later).

For example: `'A '` does not join with `'A'` in EF (but it does in SQL Server Management Studio).

Is there any fluid API setup or some workaround to make this work?

Note: unfortunately I cannot make changes in the db.

The code looks like this:

```
public partial class Shift
{
    [Column("Shift")][StringLength(2)][Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Descr")][StringLength(25)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column("FromT")]
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }

    [Column("ToT")]
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
}

public partial class Controller
{
    [Column("conID")][Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("conCode")][Required][StringLength(25)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Column("conName")][StringLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("areaID")]
    public int AreaId { get; set; }

    public virtual Shift Shift { get; set; }

    public short Active { get; set; }
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
  modelBuilder.Entity<Controller>().Property(e => e.Code).IsUnicode(false);
  modelBuilder.Entity<Controller>().HasOptional(e => e.Shift).WithMany()                
    .Map(m => { m.MapKey("Shift"); });
}
```

Comment: Is there `ShiftId` in the `Controller` ?

Comment: there is a Shift field in the Controllers table, that's why i needed the MapKey("Shift")

Comment: could you please expand the Shift and Controller class ?

Comment: i've updated the code... it does work fine (getting a controller's shift) for 80% of the records, i'm only having problems where shift.Id contains a trailing space

Comment: if you could modify the `Controller` class to add `ShiftId`, then getting the `Shift` will be just using the similar join syntax in linq

Comment: yeah.. I guess if there is no other (more automatized) way I can do that. But still it's a bit frustrating how if on db level they are linked with a foreign key, the EF can not use a the navigational property the same way, without having to query it separately every time i need it.
Anyways, thank you for your hint, I may do it that way.